# Split string into parts of 3 words Java

Tags: java, split

I want to split a string into parts of 3 words in Java.

For example:

> I want to walk in the park with my father

I want to have a string: `"I want to"`, and another string:`"walk in the"`, etc.

How would I do this?

Comment: This seems basic enough to expect you have some code that details your efforts and problems. Can you please provide such code?

Comment: This looks a little bit too broad. You probably tried something already, post it and we can begin helping you from there on.

Comment: I know how to split it in individual words, but not into groups.

Comment: OK, what if there's no direct way to group; how would you group the split string; it's presumably just an array of words that should be grouped in 3s.

Comment: The whole idea of doing `Person person = new Person(/*ID HERE*/);` is basically **bogus**. Because it requires that your "client" code that does the NEW knows the ID to use. Which it shouldn't. `new()` should figure the ID, and assign a unique value without the "client" doing anything.

Comment: I dont care about other people ;-) ... just about the zillions of upvotes I would have received for my great answer ;-) ... or maybe not! Glad you solved your problem, and I appreciate your notion to delete content that is not helpful for future readers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using RegEx

```
String sentence = "I want to walk in the park with my father";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+ \\w+ \\w+ ");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Notice that whit this expression the last word 'father' is not matched.

---

For the non-RegEx solution, I would use something like this

```
String sentence = "I want to walk in the park with my father";

String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
List<String> threeWords = new ArrayList<>();

int length = words.length;
for (int ind = 2; ind < length; ind += 3) {
    threeWords.add(words[ind - 2] + " " + words[ind - 1] + " " + words[ind]);
}

if (length % 3 == 1) {
    threeWords.add(words[length - 1]);
} else if (length % 3 == 2) {
    threeWords.add(words[length - 2] + " " + words[length - 1]);
}
```

Comment: Isn't a word at least one character long? :)

Comment: @YassinHajaj You're right. The answer updated :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For me creating a temporary ArrayList (aka `words`), and removing 3 words at a time, concatenating them into a String, and adding it to my final ArrayList worked just fine, although this probably isn't extremely performance efficient, it gets the job done & it's simple to understand.

```
// finalWords is your result
ArrayList<String> finalWords = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String str : "I want to walk in the park with my father".split(" "))
    words.add(str);

while(words.size() > 0)
{
    String str = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if(words.size() > 0)
        {
            str += words.get(0) + " ";
            words.remove(0);
        }
    }

    finalWords.add(str);
}
```

---

EDIT: Since you wrote this:

> I know how to split it in individual words, but not into groups.

in the comments, splitting it into groups of words is simple. First, you split your sentence into words, then you concatenate those words into new strings, 3 at a time, and add the concatenated strings to a list/array of your choice.